# Display message while function execution to UI without postback - asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

I am using asp.net.

I have several Insert statement on my .cs file on submit button click. I want that after each insert statement execute, it will show the message on the webpage [UI] [ex: inserted in table 1].

Like:

> button_click_event {  Insert statement
>   1   if(done successfully)
>        display message on UI for statement 1
>
> Insert statement 2   if(done
>   successfully)
>        display message on UI for statement 2
>
> Insert statement 3   if(done
>   successfully)
>        display message on UI for statement 3
>
> ..... and so on... }

just like we got the screen while installing SQL Server, we get successful message after every operation.

I don't want postback to happen for this. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you can't do this without multiple requests to the server. HTTP is a request/response protocol. While you *could* potentially just send the "page so far", it would be incomplete HTML and almost certainly render badly.

The best user experience would probably be to use AJAX for this - don't do a *full* page refresh, just change the appropriate section of the DOM based on the response to a status request.

Answer (score 0):

I have googled and find out a link through that you can achieve results as described above format.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163553.aspx

In this link when you download source code please see ContextSens.aspx page, here after click on start task button message will be display as above described format.

Hope it will help for you.

Comment: Well, that's using an AJAX request as I described - it's unclear to me whether the OP would count that as a post-back.